# Record execution of a merge sort

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib, visualization, mergesort

I have a merge sort implemented in Python ...

```
def mergesort(z):
    if len(z) > 1:
        mid = len(z)//2
        leftPortion = z[:mid]
        rightPortion = z[mid:]
        mergesort(leftPortion)
        mergesort(rightPortion)
        l = 0 # Next position in rightPortion
        r = 0 # Next position in leftPortion
        i = 0 # Next position in z
        while l < len(leftPortion) and r < len(rightPortion):
            if leftPortion[l] <= rightPortion[r]:
                z[i] = leftPortion[l]
                l = l + 1 
            else:
                z[i] = rightPortion[r]
                r = r + 1
            i = i + 1 
        while l < len(leftPortion):
            z[i] = leftPortion[l]
            l = l + 1
            i = i + 1
        while r < len(rightPortion):
            z[i] = rightPortion[r]
            r = r + 1
            i = i + 1
```

... and I want to 'record' the state of the original list, z, as the sort executes so I can use Matplotlib to graph an animation of the sort. I have implemented this method for a Bubble sort and for an Insertion sort but can't figure out how to do it because of the recursion in the merge. Can anyone help please?

This is the way I did it with Bubble Sort ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from time import sleep
from random import shuffle
from copy import copy
from time import time

plot.ion()

def generatecolours(w):
    max = 16581375 # 255**3
    interval = int(max/len(w))
    r = range(0,max,interval)
    return ['#{0}'.format(hex(r[i])[2:].zfill(6)) for i in w]

def plotchart(x,y,title):
    plot.clf()
    plot.title(title)
    plot.axis('off')
    plot.bar(x,y,color=generatecolours(y))
    plot.pause(0.0001)
    sleep(pause)

def bubblesort():
    n = len(z)
    trace = [copy(z)]
    while True:
        swap = False
        for i in range(n-1):
            if z[i] > z[i+1]:
                z[i],z[i+1] = z[i+1],z[i]
                swap = True
            trace.append(copy(z))
        n = n - 1
        if not swap or n == 1:
            break
    return trace

# Define number of items in the list
items = 16

# Pause between iterations (s)
pause = 0.2

# Define coordinates and shuffle y
x = [i for i in range(1,items+1)]
y = [i for i in range(1,items+1)]
shuffle(y)

# Time sort operation for copies of y
print('Bubble sort')
print('-----------')
z = copy(y)
print('Unsorted list : {0}'.format(','.join(map(str,z))))
plotchart(x,z,'Bubble Sort')
input('Press enter to start ...')
start = time()
trace = bubblesort()
for line in trace:
    plotchart(x,line,'Bubble Sort')
print('Time elapsed : {:.3f}s'.format(time()-start))
print('Sorted list   : {0}\n'.format(','.join(map(str,z))))
input('Press enter when ready ...')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What would the graph look like?

Comment: The tricky part about doing this for mergesort is that it is recursive. You should try to unroll it into a loop so that you can take it one step at a time (and display your graph after each step). You could probably achieve this by employing a deque of slices that need to be processed by mergesort next. Instead of recursing, `append` to the deque.

Comment: The animated graph will look like this ([view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jll0Em2hUajoYshek5e2tUJ-WumTixy-/view)). I agree - it is the recursion that is causing the headache. I have managed to pass through a copy of the original list through the recursive calls and can print out the merged portions of the list as it sorts. I now need to be able to replace the relevant part of the original list with the merged portion and pass this back through the recursive calls ([view](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kWv-1SrLfgEfJjfEDm19jx26NuIoymh/view)).